# Can't stop automatic Thunderbird updates (TB & LIghtning incompatible)

Tags: thunderbird, updates, lightning

It seems Thunderbird (currently 38.6.0 on Windows 8.1 64bit on an Acer laptop) is still automagically updating itself, although I've already set the update policy from "ask" to "never".

Not recommended, I know, but I need Lightning as well, and there are always a few days after a Thunderbird update during which it happily declares Lightning could not be used with this new version of Thunderbird.

So my idea was to go from "automatic" updates to "ask" and do this manually only if Lightning was available for the new Thunderbird release. But not even "never" updating removes this issue.

Question 1 - How can I stop Thunderbird from updating? The setting seems to be ignored.

Question 2 - Right now, there is a Lightning 4.0.6 version listed to be compatible with TB 38.6.0, but it has no download link at 
[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Calendar/Calendar_Versions]. How am I supposed to download it?

Thanks for sheding some light on this!

Comment: In the latest releases of Thunderbird, Lightning is integrated into the core so you don't need the extension, and so it isn't being updated.

Comment: https://blog.mozilla.org/calendar/category/lightning/

Comment: Lighting hasn't been updated since at least 2006.  How do I know this because, the announcement was made back then, Thunderbird also received the same treatment by Mozilla.

Comment: @Ramhound:  I use Thunderbird/Lightning in Linux.  Mine was recently updated to V45, and Lightning shows as V4.7, updated 5/10/2016.  I keep reading that Mozilla abandoned Thunderbird and Lightning, but that doesn't appear to be the case, although they don't seem to promote it on their web site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion - my fault: I am using an external drive with the TB data on different computers which had different TB versions installed. Destined to cause all sorts of problems... Getting all computers to TB 45.0 hopefully will solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I could not send emails with TB 45.0.0 so I went back to TB 38.6.0 Now to answer your question No. 1:

1. When you install your favourite version, uncheck the Maintenance/update box in Advanced Install.
2. After the install, go to the (X86) Program Files where you will find TB. Open its Folder and delete `maintenanceservice.exe` and `maintenanceservice_installer.exe`
3. Do NOT open the 'About Thunderbird' as it puts TB into an Update mode!